# using .htacess for not allowing direct urls to accsess files

Tags: php

i am getting data into a my android app from  server with php files using JSON data to retrieve the data into my app, but  i don't want anyone to access the files/directories in server with direct url , is there any way with .htaccess

Comment: Hi Uday, this looks like administration problem and not really directly related to programming. Consider asking for help on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your .htaccess file if everything passes through your index:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```